# Upload only modified part of file using rsync

Tags: rsync, cwrsync

I am studying rsync to synchronize remote and local folders in windows(using cwrsync). I have a doubt that, is it possible to upload only part of changes ?

For example, I have a 100 MB file initially I will upload it using command,

```
rsync -a /source/path/ /dest/path/
```

Then I will make some changes in that file. If I run the same command again the entire 100 MB file will be uploaded again. Instead how to append the changes made to that file while uploading ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need is the `--inplace` option.

I strongly advise you to read the related part of [rsync manual](https://www.samba.org/ftp/rsync/rsync.html) and understand what this option implies :

> **--inplace** This option changes how rsync transfers a file when its data needs to be updated: instead of the default method of creating a
>   new copy of the file and moving it into place when it is complete,
>   rsync instead writes the updated data directly to the destination
>   file.
>
> This has several effects:
>
> - Hard links are not broken. This means the new data will be visible through other hard links to the destination file. Moreover, attempts
>     to copy differing source files onto a multiply-linked destination file
>     will result in a "tug of war" with the destination data changing back
>     and forth.
> - In-use binaries cannot be updated (either the OS will prevent this from happening, or binaries that attempt to swap-in their data will
>     misbehave or crash).
> - The file's data will be in an inconsistent state during the transfer and will be left that way if the transfer is interrupted or
>     if an update fails.
> - A file that rsync cannot write to cannot be updated. While a super user can update any file, a normal user needs to be granted write
>     permission for the open of the file for writing to be successful.
> - The efficiency of rsync's delta-transfer algorithm may be reduced if some data in the destination file is overwritten before it can be
>     copied to a position later in the file. This does not apply if you use
>     **--backup**, since rsync is smart enough to use the backup file as the basis file for the transfer.
>
> WARNING: you should not use this option to update files that are being
>   accessed by others, so be careful when choosing to use this for a
>   copy.
>
> This option is useful for transferring large files with block-based
>   changes or appended data, and also on systems that are disk bound, not
>   network bound. It can also help keep a copy-on-write filesystem
>   snapshot from diverging the entire contents of a file that only has
>   minor changes.
>
> The option implies **--partial** (since an interrupted transfer does
>   not delete the file), but conflicts with **--partial-dir** and
>   **--delay-updates**. Prior to rsync 2.6.4 **--inplace** was also incompatible with **--compare-dest** and **--link-dest**.

You may also be interested in `--append` or `--append-verify` option for only growing files.

Answer (score 1):

You're using rsync to copy from a directory to an other directory - The option **--whole-file** is in effect then:

> **-W, --whole-file** With this option rsync's delta-transfer algorithm is not used and the whole file is sent as-is instead. The transfer may be
>   faster if this option is used when the bandwidth between the source
>   and destination machines is higher than the bandwidth to disk
>   (especially when the "disk" is actually a networked filesystem). **This
>   is the default when both the source and destination are specified as
>   local paths, but only if no batch-writing option is in effect.**

You need to start rsync in the daemon mode at one side to trigger rsync algorithm with delta transfers.